# Firefox Extension Development

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-sdk

In Chrome Extension Development we have Background Page Concepts. Is any thing similar available in Firefox Extension Development also. While Developing Chrome Extensions I have seen methods like

window.Bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().Bkg;

```
$(function () {
  var view = null;
  if (Bkg.account.isLoggedIn()) {
    view = new Views.Popup();
    $("#content").append(view.render().el);
  } else {
    $("#content").append(Template('logged_out')());
    Bkg.refresh();
  }
}...........
```

Where the main logic are written in Background Page(like isLoggedIn etc) and from the Extension Popup page we are calling Background page. Here for instance the background page is always loaded which manages the session. How can we have similar functionality in Firefox Extension Development.

Comment: To be fair, that's not a good way to write Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0):

All communication between the background page (main.js) and content scripts (your popup script) occurs via events. You cannot call functions immediately, so you won't receive any return values, but you can send an event from a content script to the background script that sends an event back to the content script and calls a new function, like so:

**main.js** <sup>partial</sup>

```
// See docs below on how to create a panel/popup
panel.port.on('loggedIn', function(message) {
  panel.port.emit('isLoggedIn', someBoolean);
});
panel.port.on('refresh', function() {
  // do something to refresh the view
});
```

**popup.js**

```
var view = null;
addon.port.on('isLoggedIn', function(someBool) {
  if (someBool) {
    // Obviously not code that's going to work in FF, just want you to know how to structure
    view = new Views.Popup();
    $("#content").append(view.render().el);
  } else {
    $("#content").append(Template('logged_out')());
    addon.port.emit('refresh');
  }
});
addon.port.emit('loggedIn', 'This is a message. I can pass any var along with the event, but I don't have to');
```

---

You should read this stuff:

1. [Panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel)
2. [Communicating between scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts)